# Problem with formatting LocalDateTime with org.json library

Tags: java, json, org.json

I have a problem with the serialization of an object to JSON using the `org.json` library.

In my code I have:

```java
String resultStr = new JSONObject(result).toString();
```

and in result object two fields of type `LocalDateTime`:

```java
private LocalDateTime startDate;
private LocalDateTime stopDate;
```

In variable `resultStr` I got date in following format:

```
2020-01-23T14:13:30.121205
```

I want this ISO format:

```
2016-07-14T07:58:08.158Z
```

I know that in Jackson there is an annotation `@JsonFormat`, but I didn't find anything like that in `org.json`. How to define a format of `LocalDateTime` in JSON string with `org.json`?

Comment: use `ZonedDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Did you try to convert your LocalDateTime object to ISO like that (DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE) 
                                 .format(startDate));

Comment: @YCF_L ZonedDateTime in json is formatted to "2020-01-23T14:13:30.121Z[UTC]", but I want format like "2016-07-14T07:58:08.158Z" with miliseconds and Z at the end.

Comment: try `OffsetDateTime`

Comment: @Hatice Problem is that I don't know where should I use DateTimeFormatter with org.json, I can't find this possibility.

Comment: @YFC_L I would like to use LocalDateTime, because in database I don't use date datatyped with time zone. I'm looking for possibility to define a date format in org.json library. I know that in Jackson there is such possibility.

Comment: If you require an offset in JSON (`Z`) and you haven't got any in your datebase, you've got to add it somewhere in between. I still think that uding `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` in Java is better than `LocalDateTime`. You are right, it requires you to convert when reading database values.

Answer (score 0):

In [JSON in Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), it seems that there are not much support for Date/Time formatting.

To customize the formatting of `LocalDateTime` field, we can make use of
  1. [@JSONPropertyIgnore](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) to ignore the original getter to be serialized
  2. [@JSONPropertyName](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) to annotate a new getter with ignored field name, which return the desired formatted date string, as following:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONPropertyIgnore;
import org.json.JSONPropertyName;

public class CustomizeLocalDateTimeFormatInOrgJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = new Result(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now());
        String resultStr = new JSONObject(result).toString();
        System.out.println(resultStr);
    }

    public static class Result {
        DateTimeFormatter customDateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssS'Z'");
        private LocalDateTime startDate;

        @JSONPropertyIgnore
        public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
            return startDate;
        }

        @JSONPropertyName("startDate")
        public String getStartDateString() {
            return customDateTimeFormat.format(startDate);
        }

        private LocalDateTime stopDate;

        @JSONPropertyIgnore
        public LocalDateTime getStopDate() {
            return stopDate;
        }

        @JSONPropertyName("stopDate")
        public String getStopDateString() {
            return customDateTimeFormat.format(stopDate);
        }

        public void setStopDate(LocalDateTime stopDate) {
            this.stopDate = stopDate;
        }

        public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
            this.startDate = startDate;
        }

        public Result(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime stopDate) {
            super();
            this.startDate = startDate;
            this.stopDate = stopDate;
        }
    }
}
```